# Using send() twice for sending different types of data

Tags: c, winsock, send, recv

I have a client which connects to a server and tries to `send()` some data. However there are two types of data that I need to send, lets say information about the weather and the current time (just examples).

**The problem is**: In the client I'm calling `send()` twice, one to send the weather info and one the current time, and in the server I'm looping `recv()`.

What I expected (and built my code around) is that the first time the server calls `recv()` it would only get the weather info and at the second call to `recv()` the time, however only one call to `recv()` is enough for both of the data to be received on the same buffer.

While that may not be a problem the thing is I've built my program around that assumption, and I just wanted to know if there is a way to achieve what I want (I thought of a `sleep()` between the two `send()` but that may be unreliable), so that I can save time rewriting code.

If anyone knows a way it would save me quite some time, so I'm appreciating any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no alternative to a proper message protocol on top of TCP.  TCP only transfers a stream of octets, (bytes).  TCP cannot transfer messages, structs, objects.

If you've built a large program around the assumption that TCP can transfer messages on its own, you are in trouble.

Sleep() and timer bodges will just not work in any sort of reliable or performant way.  You must do it properly and implement a protocol on top of TCP, eg. by sending a header containing the data length or using start/end bytes and escaping either byte that appears inside the data.

Comment: Ok at least I know I'm not wasting my time, I'm going with headers and rewriting this one. Thanks.

Comment: Headers hint - a good header might be all ASCII bytes, eg. [SOH]"4096"[ETX]binaryData... , where the data is 4096 bytes long.  A header like this has no endianness associated with it. All machines an read and understand it and there is no sensible limit on the data size because it is terminated by the [ETX].

Comment: the bytes should be like this: 0x01 0x1000 0x03? or are the quotes necessary?

Comment: I put the quotes in to indicate an ASCII string.  Byte byte-by-byte of my examaple: 0x01,0x34,0x30,0x39,0x36,0x03.  The ASCII string cannot contain an 0x03 ETX and so could be any length, eg. 1 MB/1048576 bytes: 0x01,0x31,0x30,0x34,0x38,0x35,0x37,0x36,0x03.